# Javascript to refocus an embedded Google Maps iframe on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, iframe

So I've got an embedded Google Map (as an iframe) in my website. 
I've also got a button (the 'Take me back to KnockKnock' button).

When a user interacts with the map, moving around, zooming etc.. Is there a way I can refocus the map to it's starting position using Javascript?

[image: screenshot of current map]

Page is here: http://knockknock.mysterybox-dev.com/contact

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because of security-restrictions you don't have any script-access to the document inside the iframe.
The only option you have is to reload the iframe.